# new comments notification implementation for a web site

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a website where people can make posts and comment on them. I want to make a new comment notification system, so when a user logs in he can see number of new comments to his posts.

My idea is to add a 'read' table, where I will store user_id and comment_id (means user_id read comment_id). But this can make some performance issue, when table will grow big.

What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve that is just to save a created date for post and comment, and a "last visit" date for the user (or "last time the user click on the "show me new post" link).

Then, you just need to get all the post and comment that have a newer date than the one you find in the user table.

Comment: i thought about last visit, but "last time the user click on the "show me new post" never came to my mind :) now i got to think how to make it perfect with your and David Zaslavsky idea.

Answer (score 3):

How about just storing the user and comment IDs for unread comments instead? Then when the user reads the comment, you can delete that row from the table.

Comment: i forgot to mention that users can reply to comments, i got sort of multilevel commenting. so when a user replies to a comment i will need to add record to db for all users with upper level comments.i thought that can make slow performance too... but now i doubt it actually :)

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to store the post time in the notifications table and then look for the user's last activity (again storing the value in the users table). Then you could do a simple query:

```
$lastActivityTime = User->GetLastActivity();
$result = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `notifications` WHERE `postTime` > '$lastActivityTime'"));
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a different storage than mySQL for this data (Like : MongoDB).

Or you can make pub/sub implementation for notifying users. (With using pubsub you dont need to store data. Just notify)